# MySQL limpeza de logs

Tags: mysql

Em meu servidor MySQL o arquivo myaccess.log localizado em MySQL/logs/ está com um tamanho grande, em torno de 30GB. Gostaria se possível zerar este arquivo, porém preciso ter certeza que não irá comprometer informações do banco de dados. Se alguém puder me ajudar com procedimentos, eu agradeço.

Obrigado.

Comment: Antes de qualquer coisa crie um Backup do seu banco (caso não tenha feito ainda) para evitar que alguma tentativa acabe com os dados

Comment: No google não encontrei nenhuma ligação desse nome "myaccess.log" com mysql. Então é necessário olhar na configuração o que esse arquivo faz antes de tomar qualquer decisão. Claro, não esqueça de fazer backup de TUDO.

Comment: Encontrei sobre log binário no MySQL, porém ainda não identifiquei se compromete o BD ou não..

Answer (score -1):

Eu utilizo um programa para edição de arquivos com tamanhos muito grandes, assim como o seu. Se chama [PilotEdit](http://www.pilotedit.com/index.html), exise versão paga e free, que vai te atender.

Segue as instruções dos comentários, faz um backup, altera o arquivo, e sobe.